# How to merge all the columns into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    3 |
|    2 |    3 |    4 |
|    3 |    4 |    5 |
+------+------+------+
```

I'd like to write a query to get this:

```
+------+
| Col1 |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
+------+
```

My question is: **Is it possible to merge all the columns into one without using `union`**?

Comment: Good to refer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80140/can-i-combine-the-results-from-multiple-columns-into-a-single-column-without-uni

Comment: What's wrong with 'union'?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov nothing wrong with `union`, its just that a lot of calculation needs to be done to get to the 3 columns format. Using `union` would triple the effort.

Comment: If you don't want to use union then you probably need to rewrite your original query to produce one column of data instead of 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes.  But it is not elegant:

```
select distinct (case n when 1 then col1 when 2 then col2 when 3 then col3) as col
from t cross join
     (select (@rn := @rn + 1) as n
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
      limit 3
     ) n;
```